# How do you return 2 variables in C#/csharp?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables, methods, tuples

Refer to method `WutHap` (sorry, I didn't write comments), I need to return both int `agg` and int sub to get the method `NumGen` would have on int `agg` and sub in Main. I know you can use arrays and tuples, but I'm having trouble doing it. If you need any more context, please ask what needs to be clarified. I'm stupid, so saying that it needs more context will probably not lead to actual clarification. Yes, I know the code is abysmal but that isn't the focus.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int agg = 50;
            int sub = 50;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                WutHap(agg, sub);
            }
            int pop = sub + agg;
            Console.WriteLine("Total aggs = " + agg);
            Console.WriteLine("Total subs = " + sub);
            Console.WriteLine("Total population = " + pop);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static string NumGen()
        {
            string[] pengs = new string[2]{"agg", "sub"};
            Random numGen = new Random();
            int mepi = numGen.Next(1, 2);
            int mepi2 = numGen.Next(1, 2);
            string pemi = pengs[mepi];
            string pemi2 = pengs[mepi2];
            string whoMet = pemi + ", " + pemi2;
            return whoMet;
        }
        static int WutHap(int agg, int sub)
        {
            NumGen();
            switch (NumGen())
            {
                case ("agg, agg"):
                    --agg;
                    --agg;
                    break;
                case ("agg, sub"):
                    ++agg;
                    ++agg;
                    ++agg;
                    --sub;
                    break;
                case ("sub, agg"):
                    --sub;
                    ++agg;
                    ++agg;
                    ++agg;
                    break;
                case ("sub, sub"):
                    ++sub;
                    ++sub;
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `I know you can use arrays and tuples, but I'm having trouble doing it.` touples should be fine for your case, what trouble do you have using touples?

Comment: I actually just tried arrays and haven't worked tuples before. I will try it.

Comment: You could: use C#'s ref/out parameters, return a tuple or make a small class.

Comment: You probably could also pass the variables as reference and change them directly (like Carra suggests) without having to return anything. Also, why are you executing `NumGen()` twice in a row?

Comment: I didn't know I was executing twice. 
`NumGen();

  switch (NumGen()`
You mean there? I thought you had to just execute it in the method so you can call it.

Answer (score 11):

You can use C# 7 syntax to return multiple values from method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var (a, b) = Foo();
}


private static (int, int) Foo()
{
    return (1, 2);
}
```

UPDATE:

Using `Tuple<int, int>`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var (a, b) = GetMultipleValue();
    Tuple<int, int> tuple = GetMultipleValue();
}

public static Tuple<int, int> GetMultipleValue()
{
    return Tuple.Create(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: Woah. Ok, that makes this simpler than I thought it would be.

Comment: @RattusRattus Welcome to SO! [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: @StepUp You should describe Tuple then show trick!

Comment: @SaeidBabaei please, see my updated answer